# A "portable installment" video game

Tags: terminology

I don't know much about video games, and I was hoping if someone could help me understand what a "portable installment" video game is. Thank you for your help in advance!

> The Legend of Zelda[a] is an action-adventure game franchise created by the Japanese game designers Shigeru Miyamoto and Takashi Tezuka. It is primarily developed and published by Nintendo, although some portable installments and re-releases have been outsourced to Flagship, Vanpool, and Grezzo."
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a slightly awkward way to refer to installments in the franchise that were made for portable game consoles, such as the Game Boy or 3DS. Nintendo has been known to outsource some of its game development for handhelds to third parties, and it is common for re-releases (old games ported to or emulated on newer systems) on both Nintendo and other platforms to be done by licensed third parties. [The Legend of Zelda: Link's Awakening (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Link%27s_Awakening_(2019_video_game)), a 2019 remake of a 1998 game, was implemented by Grezzo under contract with Nintendo, the publisher.

A non-remake example of this is [Super Princess Peach (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Princess_Peach), which was published by Nintendo but developed by Tose, and released for Nintendo's portable DS system.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!